# Is there any event to handle window alert popup's Button in js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here I have attached screenshot [Attached screenshot for window alert popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwMLT.png). This is window popup it will appear while closing browser tab. If i click leave, the tab will close. If I click stay I need to do some other action. Is there any event to handle 'stay' button in this popup?.

Please share your view, Thank in advance.

Regards,

Marutharaj M.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say its hard since there is no `stay` event for the [beforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload) window.

A dirty fix could be to attach a timer to the beforeunload event:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#stay').text("Yes, you've decided to stay!");
  }, 1000);
  return "You save some unsaved data, Do you want to leave?";
});
```

[**JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/pLgja865/)